# LESS: mixin for background position in sprites... implementing background size as well

Tags: css, less, mixins

I made a simple mixin, that helps me generate background-position coordinates in a horizontal sprite

```
.bg_h_pos(@ind, @width){
    @left: -((@ind - 1) * @width);
    background-position: ~"@{left}px" 0px;
}
```

works awesome

```
@icon_width: 50;
.icon1{
    .bg_h_pos(1, @icon_width);
}
.icon2{
    .bg_h_pos(2, @icon_width);
}

...
```

now I'd like to add a little complexity and implement background-size.

```
.bg_h_pos(@ind, @width, @background-size: auto){
    @left: -((@ind - 1) * @width);
    background-position: ~"@{left}px" 0px;
}
```

I need something like this... where background size is defaulted to 1...
if set to something else (like 0.6, 0,4 etc), then calculate new width and set background-position

```
.bg_h_pos(@ind, @width, @background-size: 1){
    if (@background-size != 1){
        @width = @width * @background-size;
        background-size: (ORIGINAL_WIDTH * @background-size)px auto;
    }

    @left: -((@ind - 1) * @width);
    background-position: ~"@{left}px" 0px;
}
```

Any help? I need some good sources of complex mixins and calculations and conditional statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are definitely multiple ways of making a bit more interesting mixins. Your example from above could be transformed into LESS code like this, for example:

```
@origw: 200; // original width

.bgw(@s){
  background-size: unit(@origw * @s,px) auto;
} .bgw(1){}

.bg_h_pos(@ind, @width, @background-size: 1){
    .bgw(@background-size);
    @left: -((@ind - 1) * @width * @background-size);
    background-position: unit(@left,px) 0px;
}
```

Where I made a separate mixin `.bgw`, that adds the `background-size` property if the parameter differs from 1, otherwise it does nothing. You could also use guards instead. Hope this gives you some idea.

As of good resources ... I would say the most extensive one is the documentation at [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/) that gives you an overview of the functionality. In addition to that, I find looking/flipping/searching through answers here on SO an invaluable source of very good ideas for what all is possible (sometimes you will find examples of pretty smart and exciting solutions to quite complex problems in LESS).